# preg match from json decoded page

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have one json decoded page and i want to scrap some data from that page.
I need to scrap this ***"value": "6fc975cd-bbd4-2daa-fc6b-1e8623f80caf|Antennas & Filter Products|Filter Products"***
[this is my json page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahNvg.png)

This is my function for preg match

```
    public function getcategories( $page = '' ) {
    $results = array();
    preg_match_all( '~/\[value\]\s=>\s(.*?)\s*\[~', $page, $matchall );
    debug($matchall);die;
    if ( !empty( $matchall[1] ) ) {
        foreach ( $matchall[1] as $single ) {
            if ( strlen( $single ) > 1 ) {
                $results[] = $single;
                }
            }
        }
    return $results;
}
```

And i call this function here

```
function checkpage( $page = '' ) {

    $vars_all_array = $this->getvarsallfrompage( $page );   
    $get_api_url = $this->catspostreq($page);
    $post_data   = $this->makePostData( $vars_all_array, 0, 25 );

    $jsonpage = $this->get_page( $get_api_url, array ('data' => $post_data, 'content-type'=> 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset="UTF-8"; application/json' ) );
    $json_decoded = json_decode($jsonpage);
        $categories  = $this->getcategories( $json_decoded );
        debug($categories);die;
        }
```

But something not working good, i have this error:

***preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given***

Can someone help me?

Comment: Message is clear, you gave an array as second parameter instead of string!

Comment: I think you want to pass `$jsonpage` to `getcategories`, not `$json_decoded`

Comment: I don't see why you need the function getcategories at all (with a preg_match_all). `$json_decoded` is an array/object, so you can easily get the 'value' out of it. smth like: `$value = $json_decoded['groupByResults'][0]->values[0]->value;`

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem.

Comment: me? You're welcome. Your regex would have failed anyway, because the `=>` is only in there when you `var_dump($json_decoded)`, it's not part of the original json, nor in $json_decoded.

Comment: Yes you, but i dont see the option where i can mark your answer as correct? And i dont want to take only values[0], i want to take values[ as many as there are on the page], how i can do that?

Comment: I'll write an answer then. To get all the values, do a loop through `$json_decoded['groupByResults'][0]->values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do a preg_match_all to get the value out of `$json_decoded`, as `json_decode()` will return (if successfull) a perfectly readable array or object.
So to get the one specific value you can access it like so:

```
$value = $json_decoded['groupByResults'][0]->values[0]->value;
```

Since you want to have *all* the values in a new array, you could just iterate the values and pass it to a new array:

```
$categories = [];
foreach($json_decoded['groupByResults'][0]->values as $item) {
     $categories[] = $item['value'];
}
```

There are built in array-functions that do that in one line and maybe quicker. This is to illustrate what you are doing with the data.

Using such a function [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) would result in this one-liner:

```
$categories =  array_column($json_decoded['groupByResults'][0]->values, "value");
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i want!

Answer (score 0):

Within your `checkpage`function you pass the value of `json_decode` to the `getcategories` function as parameter which return in most of case an array. and your `getcategories` you pass the `$page` parameter as a second parameter of `preg_match_all`

```
$json_decoded = json_decode($jsonpage);
$categories  = $this->getcategories( $json_decoded );
```

and in your getcategories

```
preg_match_all('~/\[value\]\s=>\s(.*?)\s*\[~', $page, $matchall);
```

here $page is the result of `json_decode` which is an array. that why you are getting that error